# Recursively build an object based on the keys & values from another?

Tags: javascript, object, oop, recursion, dynamic

I want to programmatically build a *dynamic* **data object** based on a **context object**, like in the example below.

```
const context = {
   ...other props..., 
   groups: [ 
      {
         heading: 'basic',
         canHaveMultiple: false,  // data.basic = {username: { type: 'text', value: '' }, password: { type: 'password', value: ''}}
         inputs: [  
            {
              name: 'username',
              type: 'text',
              placeholder: 'username',
            },
            {
              name: 'password',
              type: 'password',
              placeholder: 'password',
            },
         ],
      },
      {
         heading: 'about',
         canHaveMultiple: false, // data.about = {about: { type: 'textarea', value: '' }}
         inputs: [  
            {
              name: 'about',
              type: 'textarea',
              placeholder: 'about',
              canHaveMultiple: false,
            },
         ],
      },
      {
         heading: 'hobbies',
         canHaveMultiple: true,  // data.hobbies = { model: { title: {type: 'text', value: ''}, description: {type: 'textarea', value: ''} }, values: [ { title: {type: 'text', value: ''}, description: {type: 'textarea', value: ''} }]
         inputs: [  
            {
              name: 'title',
              type: 'text',
              placeholder: 'about',
              canHaveMultiple: false,
            },
            {
              name: 'description',
              type: 'description',
              placeholder: null,
              canHaveMultiple: false,
            },
         ],
      },
      {
         heading: 'friends',
         canHaveMultiple: true, // data.friends = { model: {title: {type: 'text', value: '' }, description: { type: 'textarea', value: '' }} }, values: [{ name: {type: 'text', value: ''},hobbies: [{ title: {type: 'text', value: ''}, description: {type: 'textarea', value: ''}} }] }
         inputs: [
          {
           name: 'name',
           type: 'text',
           placeholder: 'this is fine',
           canHaveMultiple: false
          },
          {
            name: 'hobbies',
            type: 'nested',
            canHaveMultiple: true,
            inputs: [
             {
               name: 'title',
               type: 'textarea',
               placeholder: 'about',
               canHaveMultiple: false,
             },
             {
               name: 'description',
               type: 'textarea',
               placeholder: 'about',
               canHaveMultiple: false,
             },
           ]
         }
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

The output data should be something like so:

```
data: {
  basic: {
      username: {
         type: 'text',
         value: '',
      },
      password: {
         type: 'password',
         value: ''
      }
  },
  about: {
     about: {
        type: 'textarea',
        value: '',
     }
  },
  hobbies: {
     model: {
       title: { 
          type: 'text',
          value: '',
       },
       description: {
          type: 'textarea',
          value: '',
       }
     },
     values: [
         {
            title: {
               type: 'text',
               value: '',
            },
            description: {
               type: 'textarea',
               value: '',
            }
         } 
     ]
  },
  friends: {
     model: {
       name: { 
         type: 'text',
         value: '',
       },
       hobbies: {
           title: { 
              type: 'text',
              value: '',
           },
           description: {
              type: 'textarea',
              value: '',
           }
       }
     },
     values: [ 

     ]
  },
}
```

In essence,

1. groups[*int*].heading becomes the top level property of the data object, and
2. each group along with each of the child from inputs has a **canHaveMultiple** property, which distinguishes whether the resulting object structure will be either:

> canHaveMultiple == false

```
group.input.name: {
  group.type,
  value: ''
}
```

**OR**

> canHaveMultiple == true

```
{  
  model: { 
     group.input.name: {
       type: group.input.type,
       value: ''
     }, 
     ... etc      
  },
  values: [{
     group.input[0].name: {
        type: group.input[0].type,
        value: '',
     },
     group.input[1].name: {
        type: group.input[1].type,
        value: '',
     }
  }]
}
```

The model is there so that I can easily push a new copy of that object into the values array.

So here is my question:

Is there a way to recursively do this so that the program will create the data object from the context object, and keep looking down the context object chain for any **'nested' type** (also within the inputs array) until there is none left? Is this do-able and efficient or am I thinking and going about this the wrong way?

*PS: I have been trying real hard and wrecking my head for a few days now on this but I cannot seem to get it working for Nested Objects beyond 3 levels because I am a newbie in recursion. Please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function first group by heading (using reduce) then goes recursively over the `inputs` fields. That is if an input has `inputs` we loop that too.

```js
const context={groups:[{heading:"basic",canHaveMultiple:!1,inputs:[{name:"username",type:"text",placeholder:"username"},{name:"password",type:"password",placeholder:"password"},]},{heading:"about",canHaveMultiple:!1,inputs:[{name:"about",type:"textarea",placeholder:"about",canHaveMultiple:!1},]},{heading:"hobbies",canHaveMultiple:!0,inputs:[{name:"title",type:"text",placeholder:"about",canHaveMultiple:!1},{name:"description",type:"textarea",placeholder:null,canHaveMultiple:!1},]},{heading:"friends",canHaveMultiple:!0,inputs:[{name:"name",type:"text",placeholder:"this is fine",canHaveMultiple:!1},{name:"hobbies",type:"nested",canHaveMultiple:!0,inputs:[{name:"title",type:"textarea",placeholder:"about",canHaveMultiple:!1},{name:"description",type:"textarea",placeholder:"about",canHaveMultiple:!1},]}]},]}

function transform(arr) {
  var result = arr.reduce(function(agg, item) {
    var heading = item.heading
    var canHaveMultiple = item.canHaveMultiple
    var parent;
    agg[heading] = {}
    if (canHaveMultiple === false) {
      parent = agg[heading]
    }
    if (canHaveMultiple === true) {
      agg[heading] = {
        model: {},
        values: []
      }
      parent = agg[heading]['model']
    }

    function do_inputs(parent, inputs) {
      inputs.forEach(function(input) {
        if (!input.inputs) {
          parent[input.name] = {
            type: input.type,
            value: ''
            // todo: placeholder and other properties
          }
        } else {
          // nested
          parent[input.name] = {}
          do_inputs(parent[input.name], input.inputs)
        }

      })
    }
    do_inputs(parent, item.inputs)

    return agg;
  }, {})

  return result;
}

console.log(transform(context.groups));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two snippets which might get you most of the way there.

The first one is perhaps too simple, ignoring your `model/value` part.  But it should be easy to understand:

```js
const convert = (xs) => Object .fromEntries (
  xs .map (({name, type, inputs = []}) => 
    [name, inputs .length ? convert (inputs) : {type, value: ''}]
  )
)

const restructure = (context) => ({
  data: Object .fromEntries (context .groups .map (
    ({heading, inputs}) => [heading, convert (inputs)]
  ))
})

const context = {other: "props", groups: [{heading: "basic", canHaveMultiple: !1, inputs: [{name: "username", type: "text", placeholder: "username"}, {name: "password", type: "password", placeholder: "password"}]}, {heading: "about", canHaveMultiple: !1, inputs: [{name: "about", type: "textarea", placeholder: "about", canHaveMultiple: !1}]}, {heading: "hobbies", canHaveMultiple: !0, inputs: [{name: "title", type: "text", placeholder: "about", canHaveMultiple: !1}, {name: "description", type: "description", placeholder: null, canHaveMultiple: !1}]}, {heading: "friends", canHaveMultiple: !0, inputs: [{name: "name", type: "text", placeholder: "this is fine", canHaveMultiple: !1}, {name: "hobbies", type: "nested", canHaveMultiple: !0, inputs: [{name: "title", type: "textarea", placeholder: "about", canHaveMultiple: !1}, {name: "description", type: "textarea", placeholder: "about", canHaveMultiple: !1}]}]}]}

console .log (restructure (context))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The second one *does* add the `model`/`value` part at the expense of some additional complexity.  And it's not clear to me if it's entirely correct, although I think it's close:

```js
const convert = (xs) => Object .fromEntries (
  xs .map (({name, type, inputs = [], canHaveMultiple}) =>  [
    name, 
    canHaveMultiple  
      ? {model: convert (inputs), values: [convert (inputs)]} 
      : inputs.length ? convert (inputs) : {type, value: ''}
  ])
)

const restructure = (context) => ({
  data: Object .fromEntries (context .groups .map (
    ({heading, inputs, canHaveMultiple}) => [
      heading, 
      canHaveMultiple 
        ? {model: convert (inputs), values: [convert (inputs)]} 
        : convert (inputs)
    ]
  ))
})

const context = {other: "props", groups: [{heading: "basic", canHaveMultiple: !1, inputs: [{name: "username", type: "text", placeholder: "username"}, {name: "password", type: "password", placeholder: "password"}]}, {heading: "about", canHaveMultiple: !1, inputs: [{name: "about", type: "textarea", placeholder: "about", canHaveMultiple: !1}]}, {heading: "hobbies", canHaveMultiple: !0, inputs: [{name: "title", type: "text", placeholder: "about", canHaveMultiple: !1}, {name: "description", type: "description", placeholder: null, canHaveMultiple: !1}]}, {heading: "friends", canHaveMultiple: !0, inputs: [{name: "name", type: "text", placeholder: "this is fine", canHaveMultiple: !1}, {name: "hobbies", type: "nested", canHaveMultiple: !0, inputs: [{name: "title", type: "textarea", placeholder: "about", canHaveMultiple: !1}, {name: "description", type: "textarea", placeholder: "about", canHaveMultiple: !1}]}]}]}

console .log (restructure (context))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

In both of them, we could simplify a lot if you had a consistent interface.  That is, if `groups` was called `inputs` and `heading` was called `name`, we could consolidate the two repetitive functions into a single one.